# Xamarin Forms for Windows Desktop app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a need to create a desktop application that can run on Windows machines (Windows 7, 8, 10 and Windows Server). I understand I can use Classic WPF, but prefer to use Xamarin Forms.

Does XF support Windows Desktop apps? If so, are there any gotchas to be aware of?

Comment: WPF is planned for a future release of Xamarin.Forms (3rd/4th qtr 2017) but I have not seen which Windows versions are planned for, but as Jason's answer says, *today* it only supports UWP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on Windows, Xamarin Forms supports UWP apps only.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what versions of Windows can UWP apps run on?

Comment: @DotnetDude Windows 10+ for UWP : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide

Answer (score 9):

The next release of Xamarin Forms, Xamarin Forms 3, is going to add full support for desktop apps on Windows, Mac OS and Linux.  The [MacOS support is in preview now](https://blog.xamarin.com/preview-bringing-macos-to-xamarin-forms/), but the Windows support is still in development.

As I understand it, the plan is to use WPF for the Windows support, so your solution would include a WPF project in addition to each of the other platform specific projects.  That will allow development of traditional desktop Windows apps, rather than UWP type apps.

The hope/assumption here is that, because these are WPF apps they should therefore be able to run on versions of Windows that don't support UWP apps - Windows 7 and Server 2008 for example.

There's more on what's coming in Xamarin Forms 3 on [the Xamarin Blog here](https://blog.xamarin.com/glimpse-future-xamarin-forms-3-0/), and also in the [Microsoft Build 2017 talk by David Ortinau](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Build/2017/B8099).

I was at a talk by Xamarin TSP [Michael Sivers](https://twitter.com/msivers) last night and he mentioned that there are discussions ongoing about a XAML standard that could be adopted by both Xamarin and WPF which makes a lot of sense in the context of Xamarin forms apps on WPF.